# CSVファイルが仕上がる前に、クライアントが取得操作（ブラウザ）されてしまう事態を避けたい

Tags: php

PHPで、ユーザの実行指示によりDB上のレコードをCSVファイルにダウンロードすることを可能にしました。
以下コーディングです。

```
if (touch($file_path)){
    $file = new SplFileObject($file_path, "w");
    // write csv header
    $file->fputcsv($export_header);

    while($row_export = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $export_arr = "";

        foreach( $row_export as $key => $val ){
            $export_arr[] = mb_convert_encoding($val, 'SJIS-win', 'UTF-8');
        }

        $file->fputcsv($export_arr);
    }

    $dbh = null;

    // ダウンロード開始
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    // ここで渡されるファイルがダウンロード時のファイル名になる
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=temporary.csv'); 
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_path));
    readfile($file_path);
    exit;
}
```

====質問====
クライアント画面下部に現れるファイルを開く・保存のダイアログ（IE）が、ダウンロードされるファイルが仕上がる前に表示されている気配があります。これを操作した際に内容が出力されきっていない状態の結果が画面に表示されるためです。
全てのが出力結果が出揃ってからクライアント側の入手・展開を可能にする動作を達成するには　どういった対策が考えられますか？

====追記====
最終的に以下のようにしたら、ダウンロードのCSVファイルの内容が保障されるようになりました（多分）。
IEのブラウザでしか確認していませんが．．．

```
// ダウンロード開始
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
// ここで渡されるファイルがダウンロード時のファイル名になる
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=temporary.csv'); 
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
//header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_path));        【いらない？！】//
readfile($file_path);
```

Comment: 保存ダイアログがダウンロード完了前に出てくることはありますが、基本的にダウンロードが完了するまでにそれが実行されることはないはずです。出力されきっていない状態ということですが、何らかの理由で出力内容が切れているということはないですか？

Comment: ファイルハンドルを明示的にクローズしていない(`fclose()`の記述が無い)ようですが、こちらは問題となりませんか。

Comment: ご見解をありがとうございます。
ダイアログが現れてすぐさま「ファイルを開く」ボタンを押下してしまうと
進行率が決まって100%未満の数字で現れ、カウントアップされることなくダウンロードできませんでした
という結末を招きます。（再試行というタイトルボタンになるもこれを押しても失敗）

また、すぐさまダイアログのボタンを押さないまでも、ちょっと早かったかなぁぐらいで
押下すると．．．内容が見切れております。

ApacheのaccessログとPHPのerrorログに、エラーのような記載は見当たっておりません。

Comment: @cubick　行き違いのコメントを追記してしまいました。

Comment: レスポンスを返す前に `$file->fflush()` してバッファを強制出力してみると良いかも知れません。

Comment: SplFileObject は fclose メソッドが無いので、closeするなら$file = nullしろと、本家に回答がありました。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22449822/how-to-close-a-splfileobject-file-handler

Comment: 皆様ご支援をありがとうございます。
inasyncさんとyyzさん　両方のご見解を参考にWhile文の後ろ（DBセッション開放手前）に
$file->fflush();/$file = null;の2つの構文を格納しましたが、状況に進展はみられませんでした。
つまり．．．ブラウザからのダイアログ上のボタン押下次第で内容が保障されない、ということです。
$file = null;の採用箇所が悪いのでしょうかね？？
以外に現在当方が拘っていることって、難しいのですかね？

Comment: 思った以上に根が深そうですね。再現可能なサンプルコードを添付頂いた方が早いかも知れません。ちなみに、IE以外のブラウザ（Chrome 等）で行った場合はどうなりますか？

Comment: headerをセットした後、`$file = fopen("php://output", "w");`として直接書き出して見てください。別途ファイルオブジェクトを作る必要はありません。Content-Transfer-EncodingとContent-Lengthは不要です。Content-Typeはtext/csvにしましょう

Comment: 皆様　多大なご支援を頂き誠にありがとうございます。
Kenji Noguchiさんの仰られるとおりにしてみると、毎回ダウンロードするファイルが目的どおり
最後まで収まっている状況でした！
当初からのheader関数部分のコーディングを、Kenji Noguchiさんのご提案に一歩一歩
近づけていき問題がどこにあるのか努めたところ、
結局header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_path));の存在の違いで状況が変化することを発見できました。
ちなみにheader('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');の存在の違いで変化は生じなかったので
こちらもこれを機会にとってしまいました。

記事を引用して１行１行の構文の理解が後手になっているので、皆様の貴重なお時間を拝借してしまいました。
今から今回削除した2つの構文を理解し、不要・必要を見極めてFixしたいと思います。
ありがとうございました